# Is there a free mapping tool which has its on Android SDK?

Tags: android, software-recommendations

I am looking for the functionality(s) ArcGIS provide for developing Android apps for free. What I want in specific is a tool like ArcMap where I can develop a map and convert it to some file format like (*.tpk) by which I can develop some routing and geocoding functionality(s). I know it's a long shot but is there a tool which provides this?

Comment: QGIS Android https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Android is more an alternative.

Comment: yea,I know qgis is the best free tool to develop a map.But when they say they have android capability,they meant it as u can develop the map on and android device(like having arcmap on android)